# How to import android source code(AOSP) into Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know how to import android source code into eclipse, but is there any way to import android source code into android studio. Because I want to change my IDE from eclipse to android studio.

Comment: You should rename the title to include eclipse. Misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer from my colleague, he told me that , use the file in

```
sourcecode/development/ide/eclipse/.classpath
```

this file is for eclipse to import android source code . but there is a way to transfer this file into a intellij project import file . sorry , I also don't know how to transfer. but my colleague email me a *.iml file.yeah ,this is the file that can help you crate the intellij module .
After you get the file ,copy that *.iml file to the root of your sourcecode,then you can open the intellij,create a empty project ,import module from existing module ,then in the window ,chose the *.iml file ,after that ,the only thing you can do is wait . it takes much time to import it.
so ,you can develop the android source code in intellij . enjoy it!

Comment: Could you show your .iml file in this topic? Thanks.

Comment: @Autobots You can do it like this : 1. mmm development/tools/idegen/ 2. cd development/tools/idegen/ 3. . idegen.sh  .  and it tooks awhile . you can have the *.iml on your source code .

Answer (score 27):

I know this was already answered, but I wanted to add onto this for anyone else that sees this.

For Android studio:

1. Open terminal (*nix system) call the following:

   ```
   {AOSP root}/make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
   ```
2. This will generate an `android.ipr` file in the `{AOSP root}` directory.
3. In Android Studio, select 'Open project' and select the generated `android.ipr` file.
4. Note: this will take a long time to index all the files (~2 hours). Be patient. If a dialog box that says 'Framework detected' appears, select that and hit 'OK'.

Now you have the entire Android framework loaded into Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comment What if you want to download specific AOSP/app and import only that app in android studio ?

Comment: From my knowledge,there is no way to just include an app. When u download AOSP, the /app is dependent on that build and may have other dependencies. If u want to load that you would need to do that manually.

Comment: {AOSP root}/make idegen regenerates error "make: *** No rule to make target 'idegen'.  Stop." cannot create the java files for idegen.sh to run.

Comment: @George are you sure you are in the correct directory? If it can't find the idgen then it is either moved on a newer build, you are in the wrong directory, or your build environment is not set up properly. If anything do a search for it

Comment: I never got the "framework detected" dialog box, and it gives me a billion errors about android.* not found and java.* not found and resources not found. nothing works. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have everything downloaded/installed according to the AOSP documentation? I haven't used in latest version of Android Studio. Are you sure your Android studio is installed correctly?

Comment: Update: got it working. I am using Android Studio Chipmunk Beta 3 (lastest Beta build), and my problem was - The language level was set to 11 while it should have been 8. After that, to get layout previews working, I had to add an Android SDK, however remove classpath, annotations, basically everything you can remove, and set the JDK to 1.8 (No Libraries) created after the IDEGen README. Works like a charm now!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Congrats! Yea need to make sure all versions are set properly for the AOSP version you are using. It can be finicky.

Comment: Why idegen.sh never completes?

Comment: It will complete. Either you need a better computer or wait a few hours. Ensure your hardware is what recommended by AOSP. It goes quicker without a VM as well. Luckily it only needs to be run once. If there is something wrong with the config, you will find out.

Comment: In my case it was a directory: ./vendor/qcom/ that contained looping symlinks which the idegen.sh searched through forever.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps to Migrate to Android Studio:

**Export from Eclipse**

1. In Eclipse, select File > Export.
2. In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.
3. Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

**Import to Android Studio**

1. In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
2. Click Import Project.
3. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse, expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK.
4. In the following dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not need to specify the Gradle home.)

That's all you need to do. For more you may refer to [official doc](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#Export).

Comment: Thanks , maybe I didn't tell that clearly,  the source code I refer means android source code,like jelly bean ,like kitkat and so on.

Comment: Yes by this method your complete source code will be copied to android studio

Comment: Do you mean the documentation? Like when hovering the mouse over a method and showing a window with the javadoc?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal I know you mean to the project source code , but I refer the source code is AOSP(android open source project),means the whole android system source code. but also thanks anyway.

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp If you have answer please post here and mark that correct so that if any other have question can find solution and question will be closed.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal I already post in the answer, but it tells me that , only tomorrow could I accept my own answer~

Answer (score 0):

check this link

```
http://effie.io/opening-aosp-with-intellij-part-3/
```

this has all the steps to open AOSP In intellij or Android studio, with some additional steps to fix some errors.