# Following guides on import AOSP into Android studio, still many errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I'm following [How to import android source code(AOSP) into Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531006/how-to-import-android-source-codeaosp-into-android-studio) and  (2) https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html

I have run

```
$ cd development/tools/idegen
$ mm
$ development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

I have created an SDK configuration with no libraries

[image]

I have set the project to use SDK 1.8 (no libraries)

[image]

I have removed extra dependencies per (2)

[image]

I have sourced ut/target/common/R per (2).

But there are still tons of errors. For instance WORKING_DIRECTORY/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java

[image]

I cannot build the project either in Android Studio.

I have no problem in building it in command line with "make".

How do I fix errors in the IDE?

Comment: How did you open the AOSP source code? Did you open the `android.ipr` file that was generated?

Comment: @Edric Yes. Do you know what the error "Class is in the default package android error" means?